# Use a list created in one function in another

Tags: python, function

I have a function which allows the user to input a name, toll price, and date into the list userAddList then append this list to the list userInputList.

```
def choiceThree():
    userAddName=input('Enter name of user to add a toll: ')
    userAddTotal=input('Enter toll value in dollars: ')
    userAddDate=input('Enter date of toll in mm/dd/yyyy format: ')
    userAddList=[userAddName,userAddTotal,userAddDate]
    userInputList=[]
    userInputList.append(userAddList)
```

I then have a separate function that, if the user chooses to save, I want to take userInputList and write it to userdata.txt.

```
def choiceFour():
    saveExitChoice=input('Input "save" to save or "exit" to exit.')
    if saveExitChoice.lower()=="save":
        with open("userdata.txt", "a") as f:
            for list in userInputList:
                f.write("\n"+list[0]+"\t"+list[1]+"\t"+list[2])
                f.close()
                return
    if saveExitChoice.lower()=='exit':
        raise SystemExit()
```

But for whatever reason I can not figure out how to take the list defined in choiceThree() and use it in choiceFour(). I need these to be separate functions and I can't define userInputList globally.

Comment: `return` the `list` from `choiceThree`, pass it as an argument to `choiceFour`?

Comment: @ShadowRanger Whenever I try to do this I get an error saying the list isn't defined. I'm returning it in choiceThree then defining choiceFour as choiceFour(userInputList) but I have a feeling that is horribly wrong

Comment: You *really* need to run through [a proper tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html), from start to finish. Returning and assigning variables, and passing said variables as arguments, is one of the most basic things you can do. If you don't have an inkling of how to do that, you have *major* gaps that a Q&A site like StackOverflow is not equipped to deal with. You need to learn the basics in order, not scattershot.

Comment: Just to chime in: `userInputList=[]
    userInputList.append(userAddList)` means `userInputList` will always have exactly one element, so when you write `for list in userInputList:`  (look into shadowing to see why you shouldn't use `list` as a variable name by the way) it is misleading because `userInputList` is a list containing exactly one element, which is a list.

Answer (score 0):

Create a parameter for `choiceFour()` and pass the list to `choiceFour()` when you call it in `choiceThree()`. Otherwise, call `choiceThree()` in `choiceFour()` and have the list sent out via a `return` statement in your `choiceThree()` function definition.

Answer (score 0):

Calling the second function in the first function helps.

The code -

```
def choiceThree():
    userAddName=input('Enter name of user to add a toll: ')
    userAddTotal=input('Enter toll value in dollars: ')
    userAddDate=input('Enter date of toll in mm/dd/yyyy format: ')
    userAddList=[userAddName,userAddTotal,userAddDate]
    userInputList=[]
    userInputList.append(userAddList)
    choiceFour(userInputList)


def choiceFour(userInputList):
    saveExitChoice=input('Input "save" to save or "exit" to exit.')
    if saveExitChoice.lower()=="save":
        with open("userdata.txt", "a") as f:
            for list in userInputList:
                f.write("\n"+list[0]+"\t"+list[1]+"\t"+list[2])
                f.close()
                return
    if saveExitChoice.lower()=='exit':
        raise SystemExit()

choiceThree()
```

Output -

```
Enter name of user to add a toll: user
Enter toll value in dollars: 11
Enter date of toll in mm/dd/yyyy format: 11/11/11
Input "save" to save or "exit" to exit.save
```

Data inside `userdata.txt` -

```
1 
2 user  11  11/11/11
```

(Numbered the lines above for ease of understanding. Line numbers do not exist in the output file)